# Maximum SQLite size using blob

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I want to create a database where text and images will be stored using blob.
There will be about 5-6k entries and the size of the image will be around 1MB.
That means 5-6GB of storage. Will my app be able to handle all that storage or it will crash?
I wonder cause my phone is 16GB and it will be around 50% of phone's free storage.
In case blob doesn't work is there an other method I can use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQLite itself will handle that much data just fine.
(Databases can have up to [140 TB](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_page_count).)

It might be more efficient to store large images in files instead; see [Internal Versus External BLOBs in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).
However, mobile devices behave differently; you'd have to measure it to find out which is faster.

Regardless of how you store the data, as long as you still have free space, you still can store data.